# Need help with making label of repeater visible and link button hidden in code behind

Tags: c#

aspx page:-

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptAdd" OnItemCommand="rptAdd_ItemCommand" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>

<td>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBill" Text="Make Default" runat="server" Visible="true" CommandName="DefaultBill"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Label ID="labelBill" Text="Yes" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</td>

 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:-

```
protected void rptAdd_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.CommandName == "DefaultBill")


        {
            Users objBill = new Users();

            objBill.IsDefault = true;

            e.Item.FindControl("labelBill").Visible=true;
            e.Item.FindControl("lnkBill").Visible = false;



        }

    }
```

In code behind intellisense is not detecting "labelBill" and "lnkBill"..what could be wrong ?
Also need to know...that's how u access controls in a repeater ?? like using findControl() ...right ?

[EDIT]

Changed code as follows..still not working...

```
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("labelBill")).Visible=true;
        ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkBill")).Visible = false;
```

Why wont intellisense detect these two IDs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your controls are inside a repeater, the find control wont search recursively. Try this instead.

```
rptAdd.FindControl("labelBull").Visible = true;
```